# Hover and keyframe animation when loading working together

Tags: css, hover, slide, keyframe

I'm not into coding, so it might me a silly question.

I'm having troubles with my website. I want to have an animation of a menu when loading the page so the div's height starts from 0% ane ends at 100%. After this animation I want to be able to hover with the mouse on it to slightly change it's height.

Here's the css:

```
.videos_bottom {
  height: 8vw;
  width: 17%;
  background: #1C1C1C;
  align-self: flex-end;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    height: 0%;
  }
  to {
    height: 90%;
  }
}

.videos_bottom:hover {
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}
```

My idea was to set the keyframe end height to 90% so the gap between 90% and 100% worked for the hover propriety.

If you want to se the website: marcotronconi.com (there's no keyframe slide in it yet)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To the height works, the tag needs an anchor, so I added `display: block` the the class, and remove the forward form the animation call

```css
.videos_bottom{
            height: 80vh;
            width: 17%;
            display: block;
            background: #1C1C1C;
            align-self: flex-end;
            font-size:1.5vw;
            transition: 0.2s ease;
            -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s;
        }

        @keyframes slide {
            from {height: 0vh;}
            to {height: 80vh;}
        }

        .videos_bottom:hover {
            height: 90vh;
            transition: 0.2s ease;
        }
```

```html
<div class="down_container">
  <div class="menu"> 
    <a class="videos_bottom" href="videos.html"> Videos </a> 
  <div> 
</div>
```

Comment: The div's height might be 8vw and when the mouse hovers it has to raise just a little bit, (look at marcotronconi.com) if you want to see the example.
But again, i'm not in coding so I might not be in your same wavelength

Comment: Can you give me an html example code, so I can test it in jsfiddle

Comment: <HTML>

<head><body>


 <div class="down_container">
  <div class="menu">
   <a class="videos_bottom" href="videos.html">
    Videos
   </a>
  </div>

  </div>

</body>
</HTML>

Comment: i'll edit the answer, if it solves your problem, give me a correct answer https://jsfiddle.net/4atv8z8g/

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks ;)